# Why does Aide use all my memory and swap when running?

Tags: memory-usage

I have a Linux server running on a Linode.com VPS, where I'm trying to utilize `aide` to detect any issues.  However, the nightly `aide` run uses up all of my available memory and swap (512MB RAM / 384MB SWAP).

I've tried adding a script to `/etc/cron.daily` that would stop/start services using a lot of memory (`apache2`, `mysql`) during the `aide` run.  Unfortunately, it seems like aide continued to use every available byte (including the space freed up from `apache2` and `mysql`).

Here's a graph from `munin` showing what happens when aide runs:

[image: the graph]
***Note the spike of memory usage, well into swap, when aide runs***

Any suggestions on tuning `aide` to not use so much memory, or is there an alternative to `aide` that doesn't behave this way?

Comment: Are you still seeking an answer to this question?

Comment: Probably related to the number of files you are scanning/monitoring. Could you share your aide.conf so we can determine what is being monitored. I have seen this when monitoring large files.

Comment: I'll have to grab my backup when I have a chance.  I've since moved to a hosting service that allows multiple domains on a single host account, so the VPS mentioned above is no more...

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!